# Adding signature timestamp on existing PDF signature

Tags: pdf, timestamp, itext, digital-signature

I have an existing signed PDF and I would like to add a timestamp on this signature and, optionally, add revocation infos (CRL/OCSP).

Does anyone know how I can do this in Java (preferably using iTextpdf library) ?

Thank you in advance!

Michaël

Comment: Adding revocation information afterwards is only possible using mechanisms beyond the current PDF standard I SO 32000-1, e.g. PAcES part 4. Is that ok for you?

Comment: ... Of course ISO has to be written without space and PAcES should have been PAdES. *sigh*

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are referring to adding a "document security store" and "document-level timestamp" (RFC 3161) as defined in the PAdES-5 standard. This is explained in [section 5.4 of my book](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures).

This is an example of a method that can add both:

```
public void addLtv(
    String src, String dest,
    OcspClient ocsp, CrlClient crl, TSAClient tsa)
    throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
    PdfReader r = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.createSignature(r, fos, '\0', null, true);
    LtvVerification v = stp.getLtvVerification();
    AcroFields fields = stp.getAcroFields();
    List<String> names = fields.getSignatureNames();
    String sigName = names.get(names.size() - 1);
    PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.verifySignature(sigName);
    if (pkcs7.isTsp())
        System.out.println("TIMESTAMP!");
    for (String name : names) {
        v.addVerification(name, ocsp, crl,
             LtvVerification.CertificateOption.WHOLE_CHAIN,
             LtvVerification.Level.OCSP_CRL,
             LtvVerification.CertificateInclusion.NO);
    }
    PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.getSignatureAppearance();
    LtvTimestamp.timestamp(sap, tsa, null);
}
```

Note that this method writes "TIMESTAMP" to the `System.out` if the last signature that was added was a document-level timestamp.

**Important:** After answering this question, I saw the comment by mkl: *Adding revocation information afterwards is only possible using mechanisms beyond the current PDF standard I SO 32000-1, e.g. PAdES part 4.* My answer obviously assumes that you are talking about signatures applied using the PAdES standards. Maybe that wasn't clear in my first sentence starting with "I assume".